# Boostrap let span consume space when other no longer visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter boot strap in joomla, Ive run into a slight problem, my left column disappears on tablet(how its meant to), but then the content does not consume the space of the left column when it does disappear so there's this odd gap on tablet...

How would I solve this? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/beDR5/1/)

And Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<!--LEFT-->
    <div class="span3 pull-left left_bar visible-desktop">
         It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
<!--LEFT-->

<!--CONTENT-->
    <div class="span6 content pull-left">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
     </div>
<!--CONTENT-->    

<!--RIGHT-->
    <div class="span3 pull-right right_bar hidden-phone">
        t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
    </div>
<!--RIGHT-->
</div>
```

Any help Greatly appreciated.

Comment: In all honesty it doesn't really illustrate my problem, just re-size the result window in jsfiddle.

Comment: can attach a screenshot or something of this issue please..

Comment: http://s13.postimage.org/3otbtegrr/Untitled_1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the class="visible-desktop" . With this class the left bar will always be visible on desktop and will hide on tablet and mobile .

Arrange you columns by using media queries like below to resolve the empty space you get in between them.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .row-fluid .right_bar {
     width: 44.928%;

  }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo [columns rearrage](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/beDR5/6/show)

Comment: Thats exactly what i want, but i just wnat to get of the odd space it creates when going into tablet mode: http://s13.postimage.org/3otbtegrr/Untitled_1.png

Comment: do you want to get rid of that white space

Comment: yes i need the content to use the space of the no longer there left column as well as its own.

Comment: Okie You wil have to write media queries

Comment: is there no bootstrap wonderful class like thing that does this?

Comment: as far As I remember ... no shortcut .. but writing media queries are easy .. and they really gives you the power to control your layout the way you want